# Create a list/table of UIButtons

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to recreate the list of UIButtons (that's what I think it is, at least) that can be seen all over the place, like in the Settings app:

[image: Screenshot of the settings page]

They look like the standard UIButton, but where the top button does not have any corner radius on its bottom left and right corners, the same goes for the bottom button, and all buttons in the middle don't have any corner radius.

They might not even be buttons at all, maybe some kind of table view? I don't know. What are they and how do I add them to my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually a UITableView in grouped style. Each of the "buttons" is a UITextViewCell. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html for more info.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you for the reply.